# R-Squared Calculation in GBM R Package

Tags: r, cross-validation, gbm

Want to calculate R-Squared for model created by gbm (Gradient Boosting Machine) package in R.  After running gbm function with 5-fold cross-validation, correlated the cross-validated fitted values with the observed values of the outcome variable and squared the result.  Is this a valid way to derive cross-validation R-Squared to assess model fit?  Code as follows:

```
>Test_gbm1 <- gbm(YVar ~ ., distribution="gaussian", data=Test_Data, n.trees=15000, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=3, shrinkage=0.001, bag.fraction=0.5, train.fraction=1, cv.folds=5, keep.data=TRUE, verbose=FALSE, n.cores=NULL)
>CV_RSq <- (cor(Test_gbm1$cv.fitted, Test_Data$YVar))^2
>Train_RSq <- (cor(Test_gbm1$fit, Test_Data$YVar))^2
```

**Output**

> Train_RSq

[1] 0.9762177

> CV_RSq

[1] 0.8918581

These results make sense to me:  training model R-Squared > CV R-Squared.  Also makes sense to have train.fraction=1, as holding out a test sample would be redundant (due to cross-validation).  Does this approach to calculating R-Squared for gbm seem valid?

Comment: Are you trying the fit the model on Test data ? Also just curious why you are interested in Rsq. Usually for methods such gbm, the train MSE and test MSE are used to evaluate performance.

Comment: Am using gbm for variable selection, to get from 275 potential predictors to ~30.  Next step would be for analysis of the top gbm predictors with regression.  I agree MSE train/test is usually how gbm is evaluated.  However, the folks I am building the model for are more comfortable with R-Squared.  I know that Salford Systems implementation of gradient boosting provides R-Squared for training & test sets.  If I use a training & test set, the cv.fitted vector is shorter than the YVar (outcome) vector, due to data-set partitioning for testing. Does approach in main question seem reasonable?